# calling a callback function with ()

Tags: javascript, callback

I don't understand why a callback function defined with () is only executed immediately and never again. For instance:

```
<body>
    <button type="button">Click Me!</button>

    <script>
      const buttonElement = document.querySelector('button');
      function sayHello(e){
          console.log("hello")
      }
      buttonElement.addEventListener('click', sayHello());  // function sayHello will be executed imidiately only once
      buttonElement.addEventListener('click', sayHello);    // function sayHello will be executed only when button is clicked

    </script>
</body>
```

Why does the first EventListener will be executed immediately and never work again ?

Comment: Because the `()` is the syntax to "call" the function. Whereas without the `()` affixed, it then refers to the function object itself. For demo, run this `console.log( sayHello )` .. you'll see the function definition.

Comment: In this context, `sayHello` is the function itself, and `sayHello()` is what the function returns.